# return objects rotation to original rotation after x amount of time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am creating a racing game in which i want my car to move left and right with a little rotation
which i have done so far but the problem is when the key is pressed the object rotates but 
does not come back to original rotation , what i want is that when key is pressed it should rotate but after one second of key pressing it should return to its original rotation.
here is the script i have so far..

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CarKeyboardMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject car;
    public GameObject vehicle;
    public float turnSpeed = 20f;

    private bool spinning = false;


    public float speed = 20;

    Quaternion originalRotation;

    public bool restorerotation = false;
    public float timer = 0.0f ;
    public float xtimer = 0.0f;
    public float limittimer = 1f;


    void Start () {    
        originalRotation = vehicle.transform.rotation;    

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Z) && !spinning) {
            car.transform.Translate (Vector3.left);             

            vehicle.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            timer -= Time.deltaTime;
            timer +=Time.deltaTime;
            restorerotation =true;
            if( restorerotation && limittimer < timer)
            {
                vehicle.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, -speed * Time.deltaTime);

                if(transform.rotation == originalRotation)
                {
                    restorerotation = false;
                    timer = 0f;
                }
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.V)&& !spinning) {

            car.transform.Translate (Vector3.right);
            vehicle.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, -speed * Time.deltaTime);
            timer -= Time.deltaTime;
            timer +=Time.deltaTime;
            restorerotation =true;
            if( restorerotation && limittimer < timer)
            {
                vehicle.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);

                if(transform.rotation == originalRotation)
                {
                    restorerotation = false;
                    timer = 0f;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has multiple logic errors in it and these need to be fixed.  Here's the ones I noticed after looking over your code for about 45 seconds.

`spinning` is doing nothing for you, it is always false (you never set `spinning` to true), so `!spinning` is always true.  `condition && true` simplifies to `condition`.

`limittimer` is likewise doing nothing for you, you never set its value to anything other than 1.  Similarly `timer` is always 0: you set it to 0, then every frame while input is recieved you *add* then *subtract* deltatime:

```
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
```

So `timer`'s value never changes and `limittimer < timer` (`1 < 0`) is always false.

But it doesn't matter anyway since this code (which is supposed to stop the object from rotating after it gets back to the original rotation) won't be called *unless the user is pressing a key* which specifically overrides the "return to original" behavior.

`xtimer` is never used at all.